# How do I edit an existing measure?

Tags: powerbi

I've created a quick measure and created a card out of it. However I want to format the number as a % but I can't figure out where the edit option is!! When I click on the field in the `Field` section on the right I can delete or rename but nothing else. I've clicked on the card itself and gone through every tab on the ribbon - nothing! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the measure and change the type to % as shown in this below image-

[image]